# Shiny module for downloading all plots from dashboard works locally but not in Docker

Tags: r, docker, shiny

Here's a Shiny module that I'm using to download all plots from a dashboard. You should be able to run it by copy-pasting the code and calling the function `mod_download_plots_app`.

```
mod_download_plots_ui <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        shinyjs::useShinyjs(), # we need this to be able to keep the button disabled until input changes
        shinyjs::disabled(
            downloadButton(
                ns("download_all_plots"),
                "Download all plots",
                style = "color: #333; margin: 15px;" # default style doesn't work well in the sidebar
            )
        )
    )
}


mod_download_plots_server <- function(id, analysis, plots_info) {
    stopifnot(is.reactive(analysis), is.list(plots_info))
    
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        
        observe(
            if (analysis() != "empty_choice") {
                shinyjs::enable("download_all_plots")
            } else {
                shinyjs::disable("download_all_plots")
            }
        )
        
        save_plot <- function(plot_info, plot_name, prefix, increment) {
            incProgress(increment)
            pixels_per_inch <- 100
            file_path <- file.path(tempdir(), paste0(prefix, "_", plot_name, ".png"))

            ggsave(
                filename = file_path, plot = plot_info$plot(),
                width = plot_info$width() / pixels_per_inch, height = plot_info$height() / pixels_per_inch
            )
        }
        
        name_zip_file <- function() {
            paste0(analysis(), "-", Sys.Date(), ".zip")
        }
        
        zip_all_plots <- function(file) {
            withProgress(message = "Exporting plots to png files", {
                increment <- 1 / length(plots_info)
                
                plot_files <- purrr::imap_chr(plots_info, save_plot, prefix = analysis(), increment = increment)
                zip::zip(file, files = plot_files, mode = "cherry-pick")
            })
        }
        
        output$download_all_plots <- downloadHandler(
            filename = name_zip_file,
            content = zip_all_plots
        )
        
    })
}

mod_download_plots_app <- function() {
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
        mod_download_plots_ui("zip")
    )
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
        plot1 <- list(plot = reactive(qplot(x = cyl, y = mpg, data = mtcars)), width = reactive(100), height = reactive(200))
        plot2 <- list(plot = reactive(qplot(x = am, y = mpg, data = mtcars)), width = reactive(800), height = reactive(400))
        
        mod_download_plots_server(
            "zip",
            reactive("selected_analysis"),
            tibble::lst(plot1, plot2)
        )
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

When I run it locally, it works as it should. But when I run it on Docker, I get:

```
Warning: Error in : Result 1 must be a single string, not NULL of length 0
  [No stack trace available]
```

that appears when running the line:

```
plot_files <- purrr::imap_chr(plots_info, save_plot, prefix = analysis(), increment = increment)
```

Our docker library versions are not completely the same as my local ones - they are half a year old but I don't believe this would cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new directory with these two files:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM rocker/shiny-verse:4.1
RUN R -e "install.packages('shinyjs')"
COPY app.R /srv/shiny-server/app.R
```

`app.R`

```
mod_download_plots_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        shinyjs::useShinyjs(), # we need this to be able to keep the button disabled until input changes
        shinyjs::disabled(
            downloadButton(
                ns("download_all_plots"),
                "Download all plots",
                style = "color: #333; margin: 15px;" # default style doesn't work well in the sidebar
            )
        )
    )
}


mod_download_plots_server <- function(id, analysis, plots_info) {
    stopifnot(is.reactive(analysis), is.list(plots_info))

    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        observe(
            if (analysis() != "empty_choice") {
                shinyjs::enable("download_all_plots")
            } else {
                shinyjs::disable("download_all_plots")
            }
        )

        save_plot <- function(plot_info, plot_name, prefix, increment) {
            incProgress(increment)
            pixels_per_inch <- 100
            file_path <- file.path(tempdir(), paste0(prefix, "_", plot_name, ".png"))

            ggsave(
                filename = file_path, plot = plot_info$plot(),
                width = plot_info$width() / pixels_per_inch, height = plot_info$height() / pixels_per_inch
            )
        }

        name_zip_file <- function() {
            paste0(analysis(), "-", Sys.Date(), ".zip")
        }

        zip_all_plots <- function(file) {
            withProgress(message = "Exporting plots to png files", {
                increment <- 1 / length(plots_info)

                plot_files <- purrr::imap_chr(plots_info, save_plot, prefix = analysis(), increment = increment)
                zip::zip(file, files = plot_files, mode = "cherry-pick")
            })
        }

        output$download_all_plots <- downloadHandler(
            filename = name_zip_file,
            content = zip_all_plots
        )
    })
}

mod_download_plots_app <- function() {
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)

    ui <- fluidPage(
        mod_download_plots_ui("zip")
    )
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
        plot1 <- list(plot = reactive(qplot(x = cyl, y = mpg, data = mtcars)), width = reactive(100), height = reactive(200))
        plot2 <- list(plot = reactive(qplot(x = am, y = mpg, data = mtcars)), width = reactive(800), height = reactive(400))

        mod_download_plots_server(
            "zip",
            reactive("selected_analysis"),
            tibble::lst(plot1, plot2)
        )
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
}

# This script must both define and call this function
mod_download_plots_app()
```

Then go to the directory and build and run the app in bash:

```
cd my_project_dir
docker build  --tag shiny_docker_downlaod_app .
docker run -p 3838:3838 shiny_docker_downlaod_app
```

Go to localhost:3838 to view your app.

Comment: So you can't point out the problem but if I follow the steps you proposed it should work?

Comment: I do not know what you put into your docker image thats why I created my own one